# Proportions with Time

Tags: logic

Sorry about the title, I'm not exactly sure what to call this type of problem.

It takes one man one day to dig a $2\text{ m} \times 2\text{ m} \times 2\text{ m}$ hole. How long does it take $3$ men working at the same rate to dig a $4\text{ m} \times 4\text{ m} \times 4\text{ m}$ hole?

I tried to solve using proportions, but it didn't work out. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Sorry about the tag as well.

Comment: I notice that you have asked quite a few questions already but have accepted none of the answers to them.  You might want to go back to your older questions and upvote answers that you have found useful, and accept the answer which you think is best for that question.

Answer (score 2):

Work output is often expressed in terms of man-days (or man-hours).

The assumption here is that the number of man-days is directly proportional to the volume of the dug hole. It is a reasonable assumption.

It takes $1$ man-day to dig $(2)(2)(2)=8m^3$.

So it takes $\frac18$ man-day to dig $1m^3$.

Hence to dig $(4)(4)(4) = 64m^3$ would take $64 \times \frac18 = 8$ man-days.

With $3$ men working, that's $\frac13 \times 8 = \frac 83 \ (=2\frac23)$days.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the rate of $\frac{\text{volume dug}}{\text{day}}$

So, for a man in one day it is $\frac{8}{1}\text{ m}^3$

You need to dig $64 \text{ m}^3$ so, how many days will that take if you know a man can dig $8\text{ m}^3$ a day and thus, 3 men could dig $24\text{ m}^3$ per day?

**EDIT**: Alternate method.

Look at what each change should do to your original time of 1 day.

Tripled the men working = dividing time by 3.

Doubling length = multiplying time by 2.

Doubling width = multiplying time by 2.

Doubling height = multiplying time by 2.

So your new time is $$1\text{ day}\div3\times2\times2\times2$$